# How to parse multiple namespaces xml in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath, xml-namespaces, xquery-sql

I have a table which includes an XML column and I'm trying to fetch certain columns from the XML data. Those columns are under the `PositionRoles` tag which is part of an has `INSERT` statement. Unfortunately, I'm getting `NULL` values.

Here is the XML example I used:

```
<request-broker-message version="1.0">
    <request class="UPDATE_ORGANISATION_HIERARCHY" culture="tr-TR">
        <parameter name="OrgHierarchyDatasets_schema">
            (here is not important...)
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="OrgHierarchyDatasets_diffgram">
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                <NewDataSet>
                    <PositionRoles diffgr:id="PositionRoles1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                        <POSTN_ID>0000-0000H1-POS</POSTN_ID>
                        <ROLE_ID>0000-00002B-ROL</ROLE_ID>
                        <STATUS>1</STATUS>
                    </PositionRoles>
                </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="ExistNodeCheck" type="System.Boolean">True</parameter>
    </request>
</request-broker-message>
```

And my attempt:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' AS diffgr,
                    'inserted' AS hasChanges)

INSERT INTO TMP_ORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY_LOGS_TABLE(POSITION_ID, OPERATION, ROLE_ID, PACKET_OWNER, RESPONSE_TIME)
SELECT 
* 
FROM TMP_PACKET_LOG_TABLE (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
RESPONSE_PACKET.value('(/request-broker-message/request/parameter[@name="OrgHierarchyDatasets_diffgram"]//NewDataSet/hasChanges:PositionRoles/hasChanges:STATUS)[1]', 'varchar(1)') = '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what specific values you're after, but this should be more than enough to get you there. You need to put the appropriate namespaces in the `WITH` (which **doesn't** start with an `;`, the statement ends with one), and then prefix the relevant nodes with the relevant namespace name (for example `diffgr:` for `diffgram`):

```
DECLARE @XML xml =
'<request-broker-message version="1.0">
    <request class="UPDATE_ORGANISATION_HIERARCHY" culture="tr-TR">
        <parameter name="OrgHierarchyDatasets_schema">
            (here is not important...)
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="OrgHierarchyDatasets_diffgram">
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                <NewDataSet>
                    <PositionRoles diffgr:id="PositionRoles1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                        <POSTN_ID>0000-0000H1-POS</POSTN_ID>
                        <ROLE_ID>0000-00002B-ROL</ROLE_ID>
                        <STATUS>1</STATUS>
                    </PositionRoles>
                </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="ExistNodeCheck" type="System.Boolean">True</parameter>
    </request>
</request-broker-message>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' AS diffgr,
                    'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata' AS msdata)
SELECT dg.NDS.value('(PositionRoles/@diffgr:id)[1]','varchar(30)') AS id,
       dg.NDS.value('(PositionRoles/@msdata:rowOrder)[1]','int') AS rowOrder,
       dg.NDS.value('(PositionRoles/POSTN_ID/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS POSTN_ID
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('request-broker-message/request/parameter/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet') dg(NDS);
```

I've also remove the `NOLOCK` hit, as I suspect it's being misused: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Thanks for attention, I used directly query like ...PositionRoles[@diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"]/STATUS/text()) . And it solved problem urgently. However, then  I will try later CROSS APPLY method then.